# How are built the search parameters in the url of a Drive search

Tags: google-drive-api

When I search something using the standard Drive interface, the resulting page have an url which encodes the search terms, for example (basic search):

```
https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/?tab=mo#search/toner
```

or, as an alternative:

```
https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/?tab=mo#advanced-search?q=fogna&view=2&visibility=2
```

Where can I find a reference on how this url is built (query parameter syntax)?

I understood the following empyrical;

- "?tab=mo" seems somehow required
- "visibility=2 searches all the documents in my domain (for Business Apps)
- "advanced-search?q=" is alternative to basic search
- "view=2" or "view=1" seem the same thing

I haven't experimented different combinations until now.

I am trying to integrate a custom search box in one of our Sites, in order to provide the user with results from the Drive contents (this is not possible using the standard search function in sites).

Comment: I have edited the first post, adding some results from empyrical tests

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't answer your question but I can share that I'm looking for exactly the same thing. Since Google retired iGoogle the built in Google Docs/Drive search gadget within Google sites no longer returns a result. Creating a dialogue box that returns a custom URL for search would be the most straight forward method to perform a basic search.

It seems that as a minimum the base URL for a search is ...

https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/#search/

Appending the search term requires %20 to replace spaces

e.g.

https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/#search/my%20document will return a search for 'my document'

Good luck Massimo, hopefully some can assist